# Filtering a list of tibbles based on presence of a string

Tags: r

I am trying to extract financial data from statements. I have an excel, which obtained from converted scan, where each sheet represents a page from financial statement. I converted it to a list, where each tibble is a page. Now i want to filter it based on presence of a particular string, for example "CONSOLIDATED STATEMENT OF FINANCIAL POSITION" or "CONSOLIDATED STATEMENT OF FINANCIAL POSITION(continued)". As a result I want to obtain a list only with balance sheets and then merge it horizontally.
Note: this string would be within 10 cells from the top(as a header).

```
mysheets_fromexcel <- list()
mysheetlist <- excel_sheets("file.xlsx")
i=1
for (i in 1:length(mysheetlist)){
  tempdf <- read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet = mysheetlist[i])

  mysheets_fromexcel[[i]] <- tempdf 
}

mysheets_fromexcel[[11]]
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: Start with `grepl()`.